# Sql SELECT query just shows 1 row

Tags: mysql

So im trying to get a table that shows 3 activities which have the id's of 6,7,8 and they must be from a specific country. It should show their names and the number of times they appear in the person_activity_interval but the table i get is only 1 row with the name of 1 activity and the count of all the activities that are listed. If i remove other 2 activities it gets me the correct name and count but i need a table with all 3. Do i need to use something like join or union?

```sql
SELECT name,count(activity_id) 
FROM activity,person_activity_interval 
WHERE oib IN (SELECT oib 
              FROM person 
              WHERE living_id IN (SELECT id 
                                  FROM living 
                                  WHERE country= "Poland")) 
  AND ((activity_id=8 AND id =8) OR (activity_id=7 AND id =7) OR (activity_id=6 AND id =6));
```

Comment: Use GROUP BY name

Comment: You use aggregate function (COUNT) and there is no GROUP BY clause. In this case implicit GROUP BY is performed, and the whole source data is treated as one group. Grouping produces one row per group - so you receive one output row.

Comment: Thank you. That helped but its only showing 2 of the rows insted of 3.